# How to write trigger for deleted item?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created two triggers already:

```
create trigger [insert_history] on users
for insert
as
insert audit(action_type, table_name, object_name, time)
select 'Inserted', 'users', username, getdate()
from inserted

go

create trigger [update_history] on users
for update
as
insert audit(action_type, table_name, object_name, time)
select 'Updated', 'users', username, getdate()
from deleted
```

Inserted retrieves value from inserated.
Update retrieves value from deleted.

What about delete statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would use the `deleted` pseudotable too.

It could be incorporated with your `update` trigger using `for update, delete` as your update trigger only includes the "before" values so the code for both would be the same currently.

Edit: Though then your trigger would need to check if `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)` to determine the action string so maybe separate would be easier.